# Getting random results on Travis

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, travis-ci, supertest

My tests gives random results on Travis. Here are the logs where my tests did fail on Travis:

https://travis-ci.org/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/builds/149718369

And here are the logs where my tests did pass on Travis:

https://travis-ci.org/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/builds/149560005

Both branches contain the exact same code.

And on my computer I can also make the tests pass link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Npk.png

I had also cloned my repository on my laptop. And there the tests also pass.. I suspect it has something to do with the way I had written
my tests in 100-Login.js:

```
require('../utils');
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;

var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require("should");
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var app = require('../../app');
// This agent refers to PORT where our program is running.
var server = supertest.agent(app);
// UNIT test begin

describe("A user logs in", function () {
    it('should create a SINGLE session on /api/auth/login POST', function (done) {
        //calling LOGIN api
        server
                .post('/api/auth/login')
                .send({
                    username: "jimmy",
                    password: "open"
                })
                .expect("Content-type", /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    var data = {
                        _id: "000000000000000000000001",
                        name: "Jimmy Doe",
                        username: "jimmy",
                        admin: false
                    };
                    res.status.should.equal(200);
                    assert.deepEqual(res.body, data);
                    done();
                });

    });

    it('should display a SINGLE session on /api/auth/ GET', function (done) {
        //We check if a session is created by sending a GET request to /api/auth
        server
                .get('/api/auth/')
                .expect("Content-type", /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    var data = {
                        _id: "000000000000000000000001",
                        name: "Jimmy Doe",
                        username: "jimmy",
                        admin: false
                    };
                    res.status.should.equal(200);
                    assert.deepEqual(res.body, data);
                    done();
                });
    });

    it('should delete a SINGLE session on /api/auth/logout GET', function (done) {
        //We check if a session is created by sending a GET request to /api/auth
        server
                .get('/api/auth/logout')
                .expect("Content-type", /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, res) {   
                    var data = "Successfully logged out";
                    res.status.should.equal(200);
                    assert.deepEqual(res.body, data);
                    done();
                });
    });

    it('should NOT display a SINGLE session on /api/auth/ GET', function (done) {
        //We check if a session is created by sending a GET request to /api/auth
        server
                .get('/api/auth/')
                .expect("Content-type", /json/)
                .expect(404)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    var data = "Session not found";
                    res.status.should.equal(404);
                    assert.deepEqual(res.body, data);
                    done();
                });
    });
});

require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 0;
```

And here is the actual code that made the tests pass link: https://github.com/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/blob/travis/controllers/AuthController.js

But that looks fine to me. Anyone that maybe has a clue on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what's in your local database.

Based on your other tests, which initially register a user with `username = john` (see [this test](https://github.com/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/blob/master/tests/user/000-Register.js#L20), line 20), there will be no user with `username = jimmy`, which is what you use as the username credential when POSTing to `/api/auth/login` in the test that fails (see [this test](https://github.com/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/blob/master/tests/user/100-Login.js#L18), line 18).

The tests that pass on your local machine probably pass because you also have a user named "jimmy" in your local db.

As far as why the second test fails, it fails because the session creation test fails right before it and it is expecting a session to exist for "jimmy".

Comment: No I have created fixtures which will insert "jimmy" first before running the test. Link: https://github.com/superzaky/node-portfolio-zaky/blob/master/tests/data/data.js

Comment: I have edited my question. You can now read that Travis gives me random results. Because you can now see that my branch called `travis` actually pass on Travis.